# Is it a good habit to rm zip file before packing folders?

Tags: zip

I have a folder with some files. I need to backup them daily.

I am using Debian and zsh and I use `zip` for the tool to backup them.

I am updating the folder from time to time, adding new files, removing old files and updating old files.

I noticed that zip can automatically update a zip file. For instance:

When I run `zip -r backup.zip my-folder/` at first, it will add all files.

But when I run the same command `zip -r backup.zip my-folder/` again, it will update all the files.

Is that reliable? Or do I need to `rm` the zip file every time before I pack my folder?

Comment: Another question to consider is whether `zip` is a good tool for doing backups at all.  I would rather consider `rsnapshot`, `borgbackup` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man zip`

```
zip  will  replace identically named entries in the zip archive
```

So whenever `zip` says `updating: my-folder/<file> (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)`  its actually replacing the existing file in the `archive`, which is like a `Full backup` but not an `Incremental or Defferential Backup`. Checkout the example below:

```
# du -b dir/*
1073741824  dir/file.txt
2   dir/x
0   dir/xx
0   dir/xy
0   dir/y
0   dir/z


# time zip -rv dir.zip dir
  adding: dir/  (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/xy    (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/x (in=2) (out=2) (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/file.txt ......................................................................................................   (in=1073741824) (out=1042051) (deflated 100%)
  adding: dir/xx    (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/y (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/z (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
total bytes=1073741826, compressed=1042053 -> 100% savings

real    0m10.990s
user    0m10.827s
sys 0m0.160s

# dd if=/dev/zero of=dir/file.txt count=1040 bs=1048576 
1040+0 records in
1040+0 records out
1090519040 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 8.95635 s, 122 MB/s

# du -b dir/file.txt 
1090519040  dir/file.txt
```

Now the file `dir/file.txt` has been updated with some extra bytes. Now lets run  `zip` again:

```
# time zip -rv dir.zip dir
updating: dir/  (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
updating: dir/xy    (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
updating: dir/x (in=2) (out=2) (stored 0%)
updating: dir/file.txt ........................................................................................................ (in=1090519040) (out=1058320) (deflated 100%)
updating: dir/xx    (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
updating: dir/y (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
updating: dir/z (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
total bytes=1090519042, compressed=1058322 -> 100% savings

real    0m11.246s
user    0m11.021s
sys 0m0.223s
```

It just replaced the `dir/file.txt` with recently modified file with the same name. This is the same case even if the file doesn't have new content. There are different types of backups like Full, Incremental, Differential available. Typically `Incremental and Differential` will come into the picture if the Backup mechanism is designed and put in place for the Data.

In that case as @kusalananda mentioned it would be good if you looked at more versatile tools available to take backups.

For instance `rsync` could be of help.

Also `rm` need not be run on the existing archived file every time you run the `zip` command.

If you want to stick with `zip`, go through `zip's` `add, update, freshen`. For example, `Update` case:

```
# time zip -ruv dir.zip dir
zip diagnostic: dir/ up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/xy up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/x up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/xx up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/y up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/z up to date
updating: dir/file.txt ..........................................................................................................   (in=1111490560) (out=1078679) (deflated 100%)
total bytes=1111490562, compressed=1078681 -> 100% savings

real    0m11.351s
user    0m11.178s
sys 0m0.171s
```

If `zip` is run again:

```
# time zip -ruv dir.zip dir
zip diagnostic: dir/ up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/xy up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/x up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/file.txt up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/xx up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/y up to date
zip diagnostic: dir/z up to date

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.001s
```